# How is it possible for uri.Host to throw a UriFormatException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, url, uri

```
foreach (var node in root.Find("a[href]"))
{
    var href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
    Uri uri;
    try
    {
        uri = new Uri(item.Value.Uri, href);
    }
    catch(UriFormatException)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // *snip*
    try
    {
        if (_imageHosts.IsMatch(uri.Host)) // <--- problematic line
            priority--;
    }catch(UriFormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(uri.OriginalString); // <--- gets displayed when I expected it wouldn't
        continue;
    }
    // *snip*
}
```

The message box shows up with an address like

> mailto: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster

Which is obviously malformed, but what I don't get is why it wasn't caught by the *first* catch block?

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) it can only throw an `InvalidOperationException`. This is quite problematic, because it means my app can explode at any time then!

[[snip]]

Comment: Uri.IsWellFormedUriString checks URI conformance according RFC2396 - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax http://bit.ly/b83qyw, as stated in 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters. Spaces have to be escaped in URI. I'll update my answer too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I want to say its no so good idea to use Exception for checking validity because you can use [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6skwte6.aspx) method. So you can rewrite your code and not rely it on which exception can be thrown and catched.

So better change your

```
Uri uri;
try
{
    uri = new Uri(item.Value.Uri, href);
}
catch(UriFormatException)
{
    continue;
}
```

to

```
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(item.Value.Uri, href, out uri)) continue;
```

But this is not full check anyway.

As for your question, answer is relatively simple. You are wrong assuming malformed:

> mailto: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster

URI is [Uniform Resource Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) so its [basic syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax)

> {scheme name} : {hierarchical part} [ ? {query} ] [ # {fragment} ]

obviously valid for your input. You are end with resource's URI with "mailto:" scheme.

When you try to access Host property you assume resource was Http, but "mailto"-scheme parser used by default can't parse original string for host component and hence raised exception.

So to write your check correctly you have to modify your code a bit:

```
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(item.Value.Uri, href, out uri)) continue;

if (uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttp && uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps) continue;
```

Read some info about [UriParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser%28VS.90%29.aspx)

---

Here update based on @Mark comments.

> I'm pretty sure it threw an exception when I tried to get the AbsoluteUri property too..why should that fail?

You can't pass Scheme check since it will be "mailto". So here quick test:

```
        var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost");
        const string href = "mailto: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster";

        Uri uri;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(baseUri,href, out uri)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't create");
            return;
        }

        if (uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttp && uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong scheme");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Testing uri: {0}", uri);
```

It ends with "Wrong scheme". Maybe I don't understand you correctly?

When you change href to:

```
        const string href = "http: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster";
```

It passed correctly, automatically escaping uri to:

> http://localhost/%20webmaster%20%5B%20@%20%5D%20somehost%20?webmaster

also all uri's components will be available to you.

The main problem I try to explain in first part following:

> It seems to me you incorrectly treats any **Uniform Resource Identifier** as http(s) based url, but this is wrong. `mailto:webmaster@somehost.tst` or `gopher://gopher.hprc.utoronto.ca/` or `myreshandler://something@somewhere` also valid URI which can be succesfully parsed. Take a look on [Official IANA-registered schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)

So

> Uri constructor behaviour is expected and correct.

it tries validate incoming URI for [known schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

- `UriSchemeFile` - *Specifies that the URI is a pointer to a file.*
- `UriSchemeFtp` - *Specifies that the URI is accessed through the File Transfer Protocol (FTP).*
- `UriSchemeGopher` - *Specifies that the URI is accessed through the Gopher protocol.*
- `UriSchemeHttp` - *Specifies that the URI is accessed through the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)*
- `UriSchemeHttps` - *Specifies that the URI is accessed through the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS).*
- `UriSchemeMailto` - *Specifies that the URI is an email address and is accessed through the Simple Network Mail Protocol (SNMP).*
- `UriSchemeNews` - *Specifes that the URI is an Internet news group and is accessed through the Network News Transport Protocol (NNTP).*
- `UriSchemeNntp` - *Specifies that the URI is an Internet news group and is accessed through the Network News Transport Protocol (NNTP)*

Basic URI parser is used when scheme is not known  (see [URI scheme generic syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax)) .

---

Basicly `Uri.TryCreate()` and scheme checks enough to get links which can be passed to .NET HttpWebRequest for example. You don't reallyneed check whether they well-formed or no. If links are bad (not well-formed or don't exists) you just get corresponded HttpError when try to request them.

As for your example:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=cheesy poof

it passes my check and becomes:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=cheesy%20poof

You don't need to check is it well-formed or no. Just do base checks and try request. Hope it helps.

---

> Also, the string mailto: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster is malformed. I literally mean, that string, with the stupid []s and everything in it

This string is *malformed* by meaning is not *well-formed* (since contains excluded characters according [RFC 2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html)) but it still can be considered as *valid* due to conformance generic syntax of URI scheme (check also how it escaped when created with http:).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it threw an exception when I tried to get the `AbsoluteUri` property too..why should that fail?

Comment: Also, the string `mailto: webmaster [ @ ] somehost ?webmaster` *is* malformed. I literally mean, that string, with the stupid []s and everything in it.

Comment: I figured mailtos would have an AbsoluteUri... I guess not. I'll just check the scheme like you suggested then! The Uri's are being based into `WebClient.DownloadData`, I basically want to allow anything that that can handle... "By default, the .NET Framework supports URIs that begin with http:, https:, ftp:, and file: scheme identifiers." -- guess I should include those too then.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig deep into the `Uri.Host` property (real deep), it can eventually call a static function `GetException` which returns `UriFormatException` objects for different conditions of invalid URIs. Print out the full `UriFormatException` you are getting and compare it to the ones generated by `Uri.GetException`. You might get more details out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Nick's answer:

```
private static readonly string[] SupportedSchmes = { Uri.UriSchemeHttp, Uri.UriSchemeHttps, Uri.UriSchemeFtp, Uri.UriSchemeFile };

private static bool TryCreateUri(string uriString, out Uri result)
{
    return Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out result) && SupportedSchmes.Contains(result.Scheme);
}

private static bool TryCreateUri(Uri baseAddress, string relativeAddress, out Uri result)
{
    return Uri.TryCreate(baseAddress, relativeAddress, out result) && SupportedSchmes.Contains(result.Scheme);
}
```